#  LG Optimus P690 - how to launch silently

Tags: audio, boot

Is there a way (*without* rooting) to skip the startup sound on LG Optimus P690 if sound was not disabled before turning the phone off?

Answer (score 2):

Lars Aronsson over at Androinica [seems to think you can](http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-disable-the-start-up-sound/) using an app called [Silent Boot](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot&hl=en) (though [others disagree](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1731668-Startup-Shutdown-Sounds)). Also suggested is [Android Assistant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.advancedprocessmanager&hl=en) which is supposed to automatically turning down the system volume before the phone power cycles. I haven't tried any of them personally - give 'em a try, YMMV.